# Invalid bean definition with name 'java:/TDS' defined in JNDI environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, ejb, jndi, jta

I am currently using Spring Boot and I'm trying to include a library class which is currently used in a Java EE context. In this filename.jar there is an implementation of EJB file which has a `@Resource(mappedName="java:/TDS"` injection as dataSource.
This dataSource has been configured in a persistence.xml as below:

**persistenc.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultTDSoft">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/TDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**EJB file**

```
@Stateless
@Remote({ContactenManagerRemote.class})
public class ContactenManager implements ContactenManagerRemote {
        private transient Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager manager;
        @Resource( mappedName = "java:/TDS" )
        private DataSource mydb;

        public ContactenManager() {
        }
    }
```

I am trying to inject this EJB in a spring boot via `BeanConfiguration.java` as below:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {de.mavin.model.entities.AfingEntity.class, de.mavin.model.session.impl.contactenManage.class, OntEntityIntern.class})
public class TDSoftBeanConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ContactenManager contactenManager(){
        return new ContactenManager();
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'java:/TDS' defined in JNDI environment: JNDI lookup failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.jndi.support.SimpleJndiBeanFactory.getBean(SimpleJndiBeanFactory.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:504) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:653) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lambda$lookup$0(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:92) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
```

I use the latest version of spring-boot with java 8, JEE 8.

**Any solution to this problem is very welcome?**

Comment: I'm confused what is ContactenManager I can't see this class

Comment: And what's your runtime app server?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli
ContactenManager is an implementation of remote ContactenManagerRemote interface which is actually my EJB in the .jar file.

Regarding your second question, I use spring boot the latest version and I assume that there should be an embedded tomcat.

Comment: So this will not work. You cannot use EJBs and Persistence.xml with Spring Boot. There is also no JNDI